# Native date picker - is there a way to trigger it through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to trigger the native date picker in a browser through javascript.

I want to use

```
<input type="date" />
```

I want to display it with my own styling when the input field does not have focus, then use the native date picker calendar/scroller wheels (when it does have focus).

Im pretty sure it can't be done, but any ideas or suggestions would be lovely

Comment: What is the problem here? Are you unable to style the input once you set the type to date?

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I used to have  and I have some fancy image below the input. 
When user clicked, or tabbed into the file input, it still worked like a charm.

You could try this, but I do not guarantee anything.

```
 type="text/css">
  .date_picker {
    position: relative;
    background:  grey /* your fancy background andstyle here */;
    width: 180px;
    height: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .date_picker input[type="date"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;    
    opacity: 0;
  }

</style>
  <script >
    document.addEventListener('change', function(event){
      console.log(event);
      if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input' && event.target.type == 'date') {
        var datePicker = event.target;
        var span = datePicker.previousSibling; 
        while (span.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'span') {
          span = span.previousSibling;
        } 
        span.innerHTML = datePicker.value;
      }
    }, false);
  </script>   
<label class="date_picker">
    <span class="chosen_date">2013-03-04</span>
    <input type="date" value="2013-03-04"/>  
</label>
```

Works on chrome. Not testet anywhere else, and no time for it.

Main problem - no cursor visible when focus is in date field. 
Second one - there should be an image on the right of the box, so user knows where to click to drop down the calendar, so styling is on your own.

Comment: I dont understand how you are making that work, could you show an example

Comment: I have added example. The styling is up to you, but it kind of wokrs.